# Additional borders and wrong display when using class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block" bootstrap

Tags: python, css, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I need to hide some of the columns of my table on mobile.
I use `d-none d-sm-block d-md-block` to do that on small and medium screen sizes.

This is my code:

```
    <table border="1px" class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block">Fund</th>
      <th>Why them</th>
      <th>How to donate</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for fund in funds_list %}
        <tr>
          <td class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block"> <a href={{ fund.url }} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{ fund.name }}</a></td>
          <td> {{ fund.description|safe }}</td>
          <td> <a href={{ fund.bank_details }} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Go to website</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

When I'm not additing these classes, my table looks fine:
[image]

However, after I add this `class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block"`, some strange border appears around a column I want to hide:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this change **block** by **table-cell**

```
class="d-none d-sm-table-cell..
```